# What does it mean by automatically lifted?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

## What does it mean by automatically lifted?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

**The ban will be lifted automatically by the system** when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received.

I am a software engineer so I doubt that the system itself can actually evaluate the updates to the questions. It probably requires input from humans.

Do people regularly look at closed questions and re-evaluate them? It seems to me that once a question is closed there is a strong bias against reopening it, thus being blocked from asking questions is hopeless.

I have a high reputation (top 10% for the year) and I thought this would prevent question bans so I had no idea that I had to be very careful about asking questions.

If I knew this I would have asked some easy questions to get my question reputation up before I asked the very difficult ones. Stack Exchange doesn't seem to be very good at communicating this crucial information.

---

I don't think that this is a duplicate because I was originally thinking that artificial intelligence might examine the questions. That people look at the questions and that the questions are put to the top of the home page so that they can be reviewed were two aspects that may be unique to this question.

When referring to the other post it says that the ban will be lifted from other positive contributions. I currently have a reputation that is in the top 10% for the year why is that not enough positive contributions?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I am already doing OK on answering questions. I am still in the top 10% reputation for the whole year so I don't understand why I got the question ban.

Comment: Good work. Keep answering questions. Submitting constructive edits has also been alleged to help. Remember that you get a "free" question every six months. Make it a good one and that should help you a lot in getting out. Above all, take your time and post good, researched questions and answers. Punching out something low quality quickly is a good way to attract downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system checks your questions. If they start receiving more upvotes (the exact amount is not disclosed), it will lift the question ban.

Comment: But that only works if someone ever looks at them again. I have found that is generally not the case with closed questions. Once they are closed they are dead.

Comment: @polcott if you edit your questions they get bumped to the home page

Comment: It is only on the active sort order tab of the home page

Comment: @polcott which is the default for most users.